Advice on using limiters for circuit protection in HF circuit
I am designing a receiver amplification circuit and I'd like some advice. We operate in the 10-20 MHz range, and in proper operation receive input signals on the order of -35 dBm. Our current RF chain is as follows:
Limiter -> Low pass filter -> Low noise amplifier #1 -> Low noise amplifier #2 -> Switch #1 -> Switch #2

This circuit provides us +45 dB of amplification during receive operation and -75 dB of isolation while we are transmitting, while switching between transmit and receive mode in under 50 ns. The device on the output of my receive path amplification circuit has a maximum input rating of +10 dBm. In normal operation (assuming -35 dBm signal to be amplified) the output of our receive circuit should be within the specs for our device.
The scenario I am concerned with is when the input signal is larger than -35 dBm. Our current design (with the limiter at the front) ensures that the input to the circuit is no greater than +9 dBm. After one or two stages of amplification, this signal would become large enough to damage components later in the RF path. My idea to protect against this is to add extra limiters after each amplifier, so the signal strength after amplification isn't too great. The new design would be as follows:
Limiter #1 -> Low pass filter -> Low noise amplifier #1 -> Limiter #2 -> Low noise amplifier #2 -> Limiter #3 -> Switch #1 -> Switch #2

How reasonable is this design? Are there any drawbacks to having so many limiters along the same RF path? Is there a better way to protect my circuit? Any advice would be appreciated!
The components I am using:

Limiter: RLM-521-2WL+
Filter: SCLF-21.4+
Amplifier: TSS-13LN+
Switch: M3SWA2-63DRC+


Your strange attempts at some form of block diagram are better served by, a block diagram and not what you have posted. In fact, a block diagram and a circuit schematic are likely to be needed if you want a decent answer. How reasonable is this design <-- there is no design to make an assessment of.

@Andyaka I understood it well enough; the chain is linear and the list delimiters clear. The main downside is the quoted text/code has a scroll bar. Perhaps you could improve the post by drawing such a diagram?

Theo -- have you considered a VGA (variable gain amplifier) or AGC (automatic gain control) system?  Are you concerned about distortion from the limiters at all; is this a CW application, or is there modulation of importance here?  Or if wideband, is harmonic distortion an issue? (I understood "10-20MHz" to be total bandwidth, or perhaps a center frequency somewhere in that range, but if that's only the fundamental range and harmonics important, that would be important information to add to the question.)

If the limiters and the transistors in the LNA's can handle the power in the highest input power case then it is safe (you should compute the levels at each block in the chain for that case).
There is then still the drawback of deterioration of NF, especially by the input limiter. And there is the risk of causing distortion whenever the intended signal would be a bit high and the limiters would start cllipping it. Especially the second limiter. So you should also compute the levels along the chain for that specific case.
It's a trade-off:

Limiting signal levels that could be damaging to a safe level.
Avoiding too much distortion for signals that should remain clean.
Keeping the noise figure low enough.

Perhaps you will find that leaving one of the limiters out will still give a safe enough protection while having less of the disadvantages.
